# RAID 5 Goofy Partitions

Tags: windows-server-2012, raid-5

My apologies if this is a stupid question. Hopefully the answer is stupid too.

Brand new Windows Server 2012 with RAID 5. Everything is properly configured and installed, running great... I think.

I've never worked with a RAID 5 before. I understand the distributed parity... well mostly.

When I view the drives in Computer I see:

C: OS / 30GB

D: Data Source 1 / 1.75TB

E: Data Source 2 / 50GB

All three drives are 1.0TB. I didn't expect to have all 3TB at my disposal but why are the drives partitioned in this manner? Should I save data to C: as I would on a computer without a RAID 5 and expect the RAID controller to distribute the data appropriately or must I specifically select the D: drive to save new data to?

Hope my concern makes sense!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How is your RAID implemented? Is it a hardware RAID controller or a softRAID like Windows' "Dynamic Disks"? Also, please learn the differences between partitions, drives and volumes.

Comment: Hardware raid. I know the difference, thanks for being critical.